# C# the best way to edit strings MS Word from database?

Tags: c#, winforms

I will be building a desktop application that should interact with a database, I will need to build an API logically to contact the database remotely and retrieve data from there.

[I was given a word file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1wNy.png) and I will be updating values where the black is the values I'm getting from the database. I will sometimes have to print the file.

I however not sure what's the best way to do this. Do I need to modify the Word file and return it to the default value each time? Should I use reports instead or something else?

Comment: Do you know about the [Microsoft Office Interop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328912)? Maybe it is the starting point.

Comment: So In your opinion, playing around with the word file is better then making a report or anything else?

Comment: No. I thought the requisite was to modify the Word document, sorry for misunderstanding it. If it is an option to make a report and completely get rid of the Word document, i would go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no 'best of the best' practises

You may use [DocX from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/)

You may also get a direct document access using [ms office interop word namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document.aspx)

(afaik)